# How to disable Microsoft's decorations of tchar.h in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tchar

By default Microsoft's Visual Studio is using `<tchar.h>` and defines `main` as `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`. This can be usefull but not always.

How to disable this in default new project?

**UPDATE**

I want to create empty projects with simple `main`s...

Comment: What do you mean by "disable" it? Do you want to have the wizard generate different code or you asking how to setup a project that's explicitly ansi/wchar?

Comment: Depending on your project settings TCHAR defaults to char for mutlibyte  or wchar_t for unicode projects. You can always rewrite main as int main() or int main(int argc, char* argv[]) and override this without having to worry about TCHAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an empty project and use plain old `main`:

1. In Visual Studio, choose File -> New -> Project...
2. Select Console Application and give it a name.
3. In the Wizard, choose Application Settings.
4. Select Empty project.
5. Click Finish.
6. Add a .cpp file to the project.
7. In the new .cpp file, implement `main`.

For example:

```
#include <iomanip>    
#include <iostream>

int main(int cArgs, char **ppszArgs) {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx) guide from MSDN.